# Can't connect to wifi (Eduroam) with RTL8187SE

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, certificate

I can't connect to eduroam on my netbook, which has an RTL8187SE wifi adapter (rev 22). The hardware is quite old, but it can connect to other networks just fine. I'm on bunsenlabs linux 10.5, and the wifi adapter is using rtl818x_pci driver, version 4.19.0-17-686-pae

Here is my `dmesg` output: https://pastebin.com/cEr7TBAQ. Note that the output lists `status=10` as the reason for not being able to associate with the AP, but I have also seen `status=18`. This seems to vary by physical location - maybe different buildings have different AP hardware.

I have tried the following:

- The usual method as described here (and verified by an IT staff): https://onesearch.library.utoronto.ca/ic-faq/41003
- With certificates provided by the university
- Using a different distro (the latest void linux)
- Using a different certificate as outlined here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/901234/cannot-connect-to-eduroam
- Using the eduroam configuration assistant: https://cat.eduroam.org/
- With `system-ca-cert=false` : https://askubuntu.com/questions/573295/cannot-connect-to-eduroam-from-ubuntu

I don't know what else to try. IT told me that they don't even see the connection attempts on their end. Could this be a driver issue or is my hardware just not supported?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether the IT staff can see connection attempts depends entirely on where they're looking. Modern Wi-Fi networks are centrally managed, and failed associations usually don't get sent to the controllers at all, they're only seen in the AP logs.

The dmesg log shows the system's trying to associate with multiple APs, but the associations are rejected with reason code 10. This translates to AP not being able to support the capabilities the client's requesting. Other mentioned reason code is 18, which means the AP can't support the requested data rates. The client's Realtek RTL8187SE, which is a 2.4GHz b/g device that can support max 54Mb/s data rates.

It may be that the network doesn't support 2.4GHz at all. If it does, low data rates are probably disabled (a common technique to prevent stuck client  -issue in 2.4GHz networks). If only the 54Mb/s data rate is allowed, older clients can easily have this kind of problems. Due to interference, distance or any of the other myriad 2.4GHz issues the client might not be able to request full speed connection. Enabling data rates down to 36Mb/s could resolve the situation.

The only other option I can really see is getting a new USB Wi-Fi adapter that supports ac-standard, if not current ones.